# How to include new packages to path with VS Code?

Tags: c++, windows, include

I am a C++ beginner and I'm doing a project in VS Code on Windows 64 bit.

I need to do some plotting so I'd like to use the Python matplotlib wrapper matplotlibcpp.

I have saved the header file matplotlibcpp.h in the same folder as my project file, but how do I include all the matplotlibcpp dependencies (like Python.h and its dependencies) to the path?

The Python.h file is on my computer already from anaconda, which I assume contains all the dependencies needed.

Comment: Including the headers should be the easy part. Linking the libraries and dealing with dlls can be more difficult (you did not mention your OS). You may want to get familiar with what goes on behind the scenes (if you just use coderunner or similar): [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) What I am takilng about is the JSON files used to configure your compiler ..

Comment: @drescherjm : I admit I have no idea what's going on. I find VS Code very unintuitive compared to jupiter for python. I'm also new to c++. Does it not suffice to place the required header file in the same folder as my project file? For some reason when I try to compile, VS Code still tells me the header file was not found.

Comment: ***Does it not suffice to place the required header file in the same folder as my project file?*** On the simplest project yes. On most open source libraries no that won't work. My advice again is to spend some time to understand how your tools work. Although you may be getting ahead of yourself by trying to tackle a difficult task at this point.

Comment: @drescherjm: I now see how to use JSON file to add stuff to include path. Now my issue is, I'm not sure what to include. The file I need is python.h, and all it's dependencies. Python.h is contained in Anaconda, but some of the dependencies needed like numpy are not included in the same folder. In any case, the link you sent doesn't explain much about this. If you know of any other link where I can learn more about json/including stuff that'd be great. Thanks.